# How to do a partial update on contacts using Google API Java client?

Tags: java, android, google-api-java-client

I'm using the lightweight Google API Java client to modify contacts.

There are a few samples for the API showing how to do partial updates (i.e. via HTTP PATCH), but Google Contacts specifically doesn't seem to support PATCH . The docs also specify that contacts updates done via PUT need to include the full information about the contact since any existing data omitted in the PUT request will be removed from the contact.

So what's the easiest procedure to read a contact, modify its data and update it? The client API has this nice `AtomParser` that takes the response from the HTTP GET request and populates members in my class, but unless my class contains every possible field that a contact could have, I might not read in all the data and as such delete data during the HTTP PUT.

My only guess is that I'll have to skip all the cool AtomParser witchcraft and just use a plain old XML parser to read the incoming feed, extract the information I need and then do an HTTP PUT on it. But that seems a bit absurd, given all the functionality int he API client. Is there a better way?

I'm secretly hoping there is an equivalent to this:

```
HttpRequest request = transport.buildPatchRequest();
request.setUrl(getEditLink());
AtomPatchRelativeToOriginalContent content =
    new AtomPatchRelativeToOriginalContent();

content.namespaceDictionary = Namespace.DICTIONARY;
content.originalEntry = originalEntry;
content.patchedEntry = modifiedEntry;
request.content = content;

return RedirectHandler.execute(request).parseAs(getClass());
```

Comment: @Arjan: True, although these posts often fall short of 5 votes, surprisingly enough. Since the user will be completely oblivious to this unless the post ends up getting migrated, I figured a little hint might help too. I see your point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what [GenericXml](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.2-alpha/com/google/api/client/xml/GenericXml.html) was designed for: it stores arbitrary XML that you are not using in your application so you can safely use the PUT method.  Simply extend it in your data model classes.  A good example of GenericXml can be found in the [sample for the Content API for Shopping](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/content/sample-apps/java/).  They also have a [detailed guide of the XML model](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/content/developers_guide_java.html#modelling) including a discussion of GenericXml.  Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Full disclosure: I am an owner of the [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) project.

Comment: Wow, Yaniv himself! Good to see you on Stack Overflow. Btw, what support forum would you suggest for questions like this? (Or do you frequent Stack Overflow regularly?)

Comment: Btw, works like a charm. You're a genius! Thanks for this great library.

Comment: Thanks.  Glad to see such enthusiasm for the library!  Stack Overflow is a great forum.  Alternatively, you can use the Google Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-api-java-client).  See also the support page (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Support).